# Magnetic equivalent of a pointy edge at a voltage

Tags: electromagnetism, geometry

A pointy edge set at a given electric voltage will usually induce localized but high potential gradients, hence high electric fields.

Is there something equivalent for magnetic fields? A simple geometric/electromagnetic configuration that can create large but localized magnetic fields/vector potential gradients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is there something equivalent for magnetic fields?"

It cannot be precisely equivalent because the "point effect" originates from the re-distribution of electrical charges.

"A simple geometric/electromagnetic configuration that can create large but localized magnetic fields/vector potential gradients?"

Yes, magnetic fields "prefer to travel through" materials that have high magnetic permeabilities. This allows creating strong but localized magnetic fields.

An example/application of this can be found in "flux concentrators" (look at figure I took from google images). Here, they are used to direct the flux into a smaller area; which amplifies the field at the center. This technique is becoming a popular way to increase the sensitivity of atomic magnetometers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for more interesting answers, I'll post what I think is the geometric equivalent of a pointy edge:

[image: A tapered spiral]

A tapered spiral, but obviously with the spiral return back on the untapered end so that we have a closed loop while also contributing to the magnetic gradient